# Springboot jetty web socket client annotation doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, websocket, jetty

I developed web socket client with java springboot.
I used jetty websocket library while add below line on build.gradle

```
compile group: 'org.eclipse.jetty.websocket', name: 'websocket-client', version: '9.4.12.v20180830'
```

I made web socket event handler like below - SimpleEchoSocket.java.

```
package com.iimp.pom.socket;

import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.Session;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.annotations.OnWebSocketClose;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.annotations.OnWebSocketConnect;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.annotations.OnWebSocketMessage;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.annotations.WebSocket;

import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

@WebSocket(maxTextMessageSize = 64 * 1024)
public class SimpleEchoSocket{

    private final CountDownLatch closeLatch;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private Session session;

    public SimpleEchoSocket(){
        this.closeLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    }

    public boolean awaitClose(int duration, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException{
        return this.closeLatch.await(duration,unit);
    }

    @OnWebSocketClose
    public void onClose(int statusCode, String reason){
        System.out.printf("Connection closed: %d - %s%n",statusCode,reason);
        this.session = null;
        this.closeLatch.countDown(); // trigger latch
    }

    @OnWebSocketConnect
    public void onConnect(Session session){
        System.out.printf("Got connect: %s%n",session);
        this.session = session;
        try{
//            CommonGlobalVariable.webSocketSession = session;
            Future<Void> fut;
            fut = session.getRemote().sendStringByFuture("Hello");
            fut.get(2,TimeUnit.SECONDS); // wait for send to complete.
        }catch (Throwable t){
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @OnWebSocketMessage
    public void onMessage(String msg){
        System.out.printf("Got msg: %s%n",msg);
    }
}
```

Also, I made connection part like below.

```
String destUri = "ws://"+body.get("host").toString()+"/va?api-key="+body.get("apiKey").toString()+"&plate=img";

            WebSocketClient client = new WebSocketClient();
            SimpleEchoSocket socket = new SimpleEchoSocket();

            client.start();
            URI echoUri = new URI(destUri);
            ClientUpgradeRequest requestws = new ClientUpgradeRequest();
            requestws.setSubProtocols("va-metadata");

            client.connect(socket,echoUri,requestws);
            System.out.printf("Connecting to : %s%n",echoUri);
```

As a result, I guess successfully connected to web socket server for I found the logs from server.
However codes in @OnWebSocketConnect annotation method are not executed.

How can I run the codes in SimpleEchoSocket.java?

Comment: What specifically happens? or doesn't happen?   I can see that your use of `Future.get` in the onConnect will not allow messages to start being received until you return from onConnect.

Comment: `version: '9.4.12.v20180830'` - upgrade to at least `9.4.43.v20210629`

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt Thank you dear!! I removed the codes about Future thing, finally I could get message from the server with _@onWebSocketMessage_. I'm sorry but  I wish you could help me again. This ws client have to connected with multiple servers, then how could I know which server sent message at _@onWebSocketMessage_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out by referring to the comment of Joakim.

I changed the SimpleEchoSocket.java like below.

```
 @OnWebSocketConnect
    public void onConnect(Session session){
        System.out.printf("Got connect: %s%n",session);
        this.session = session;
        try{
//            CommonGlobalVariable.webSocketSession = session;
//            Future<Void> fut;
//            fut = session.getRemote().sendStringByFuture("Hello");
//            fut.get(2,TimeUnit.SECONDS); // wait for send to complete.
        }catch (Throwable t){
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @OnWebSocketMessage
    public void onMessageString(Session session, String msg){
        System.out.println("getRemoteAddress1:"+session.getRemoteAddress());
        String vaHost = session.getRemoteAddress().toString().replaceAll("/", "");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.printf("Got msg: %s%n",msg);
    }

    @OnWebSocketMessage
    public void onMessageBuffer(Session session, byte[] byteArray, int offset, int length) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("onMessageBuffer");
        System.out.println("getRemoteAddress2:"+session.getRemoteAddress());
        FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File("C:/files/ws/"+System.nanoTime()+".jpg"), byteArray);
    }
```

Thank you, Joakim!